# Using MySQL CONVERT_TZ in django ORM

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

I am using the CONVERT_TZ MySQL function to convert datetime saved into the database into other timezone while running query. But I want to do the same thing with Django ORM due to performance issues with the next steps. Below is the code I am doing.

```
boarding_stations = StationPoints.objects.filter(bus_id__in=bus_ids, station_id=sourceStation).annotate(coverted_timezone=Func(F('reachedTime'), '-08:00', '+05:30', function='CONVERT_TZ'))
```

The above code returns FieldError as it says  **`Cannot resolve keyword '-08:00' into the field.`**
What's the correct way to use this MySQL function?

Comment: Did the problem resolve?

Comment: This solution did not worked. I converted user input time to UTC and then filtered data.

Answer (score 0):

The `Func` function in Django ORM is used to generate SQL functions for the database engine to execute. Currently, you are trying to pass the `timezone` offset values as string literals, which is not possible because Django ORM will treat them as database field names, resulting in the `FieldError` you are seeing.

You can use [`f-strings`](https://docs.python.org/3.12/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals) so:

```py
from django.db.models import F, Func, Value
from django.db.models.functions import Cast, RawSQL

boarding_stations = StationPoints.objects.filter(bus_id__in=bus_ids, station_id=sourceStation).annotate(
    converted_timezone=RawSQL(
        f"CONVERT_TZ({Cast(F('reachedTime'), output_field=Value('datetime'))}, '-08:00', '+05:30')",
        ()
    )
)
```

Comment: You need to change the import statement of `RawSQL` i.e `from django.db.models.expressions import RawSQL`. How can I pass the "Asia/Kolkata" or another timezone name in this expression? Because in SQL I'm using it that way.

Comment: Also, i'm unable to use `.filter(converted_timezone__time__gte=onwarddatetime.time())` on this annotate. where onwarddatetime is a datetime type object.